# How can I fuzz a http server?

Tags: http, webserver, fuzzing

I was researching fuzzing using AFL and hongofuzz and they mainly support applications that run in the terminal. After that I came across a list of resources for network fuzzers, and found afl-net which was well maintained. I tried using aflnet but it does not support the http protocol. I do not want to edit the code of the http server and try to make it work that way. Is there anyway to fuzz http servers?

Comment: Have you even tried googling "http fuzzer"? I did, and immediately found 6 different http fuzzers. Please, at least put a minimum of effort in before asking a question.

Comment: That is the wrong type of fuzzer. Either the search results you are talking about are dumb fuzzers or http fuzzers that do not fuzz the binary but the actual webpage. Meaning you give them a wordlist of directories or an xss list and it tries it on the site.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure afl-net can be configured to do what you want, it is probably not needed. When fuzzing network services, the typical method is to either 1. modify the application source code to read from standard input/file instead of a network socket or 2. using a dynamic library hook at runtime (e.g. [preeny](https://github.com/zardus/preeny)) to achieve the same behavior. This allows AFL/honggfuzz to function as normal.

> I do not want to edit the code of the http server and try to make it work that way.

In some cases, this may be necessary to get a program to work at all with a fuzzer, or to optimize it for fuzzing/to isolate fuzzing to a minimal code section.

For future research, there are plenty of blog posts and tutorials out there for fuzzing popular web servers.